# Загрузка/сохранение настроек множества модулей приложения

Tags: java, c#, архитектура

Однажды возникла задача сохранять настройки приложения в файле. В приложении существуют различные классы, требующие конфигурирования. При этом приложение развивалось, добавлялись новые настройки и было неудобно после изменения классов корректировать в других местах загрузку/выгрузку настроек. Я попытался немного структурировать этот процесс.

В общих чертах система устроена так: каждый класс умеет сохранять свои параметры в формате XML в отдельном узле и точно так же умеет загружать их из отдельного узла.

```
public interface IConfigurable
{
    void SaveConfig(XmlDocument xmlDoc, XmlNode localRoot);
    void LoadConfig(XmlNode node);
    String ModuleName { get; }
}
```

Процессом конфигурирования управляет отдельный класс **XmlConfig**. Я в нем регистрирую классы, которые хочу сконфигурировать:

```
        xmlConf = new XmlConfig();
        xmlConf.FileName = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\config.xml";
        xmlConf.RootName = "myconfig";
        xmlConf.AddMember(SomeClass1);
        xmlConf.AddMember(SomeClass2);
        xmlConf.AddMember(SomeClass3);
```

а затем вызываю метод **XmlConfig.ConfigureAll()**, который ищет по имени ModuleName в XML файле узел, отвечающий за конкретный класс и передает ему этот узел. Класс конфигурирует сам себя и возвращает управление конфигуратору, который переходит к следующему классу.

```
public void ConfigureAll()
    {
        foreach (IConfigurable iconf in objectsToConfigure)
        {

            XmlNode node = confDocument[rootName][iconf.ModuleName];
            iconf.LoadConfig(node);
        }
    }
```

Но я нигде не видел подобных реализаций и вообще мало информации нашел по теме конфигурирования разных модулей приложения. Возможно я изобрел велосипед и есть более элегантные способы загрузки/сохранения множества различных параметров?

Как вы решаете такие задачи? Что почитать на эту тему?

Answer (score 1):

1. Почитайте по-поводу [apache-commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) - правда речь идет только о Java, так что не взыщите.
2. Мне лично очень также нравится система управления конфигурацией приложения [реализованная в Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), особенно приятно с ней работать при использовании аннотаций [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/SharedPreferencesHelpers)
3. В vanilla Java популярностью до сих пор пользуется "родная" система управления конфигурацией через [properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)